# About formatted pen drive

Tags: windows-7

How can I repair my formatted pen drive?

My pendrive doesn’t show free memory in diskpart section. Actually *(originally?)*, my pendrive could not show free space and it was showing only FAT32. At that time I tried to format it. When I clicked the format option, I got a system error that 'format could not complete'.

Since that time, every time I connect my USB drive, I get a message to format; and, as usual, format cannot complete. So now my pendrive is useless.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No-one's going to mail you. If you're interested make the effort to return here after posting your question (which could have been worded better). Try formatting your drive in Linux. Also consider the possibility that the pen drive, probably made of cheap materials, is simply dead.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should do is run low-level diagnostics software on the flash drive. The manufacturer should offer software for this purpose (they do with hard drives). If not, you could probably find a free generic tool on google.

Rule out hardware failure before advancing any further.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, press Start, type in "Disk Management" and then "create and format partitions" and it should say "Disk One" and then a black/blue/green area. Right click where it sais "(F:)" (or your flash drives letter), then click "delete" and once it is done, do that except select "create a new partition". I would advise you to create it as NTSF instead of FAT32 for several reasons.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to take the data in the pen drive back. find a recovery software or just use the recovery software from jihosoft (the same website with the free eraser ). that you can see if you can take your data back.

if you just want to format the pen drive.

Try to find a  Eraser to erase or empty the drive.see if the drive can work. Maybe it is just because the virus made your pen drive has bad sector or something. clean it.[free eraser here](http://www.jihosoft.com/security/eraser.html)  you can chose format it again after erase the drive and